# Difference in mount vs file manager mount

Tags: mount, samba, filemanager

I have a shared Samba drive that previous to 22.10 the command
`sudo mount -t cifs -o user=larry,pass=XXX,uid=1000,gid=1000,vers=1.0 //10.0.0.23/Misc   /smb/fs1/Misc`
worked fine, but now on 22.10, video files won't play.  I've searched dozens of different "How to" pages and tried dozens of different options, nothing helped.

Then I just happened to notice that if I use the file manager, goto "Other Locations", then under "Networks" select the machine and the shared folder it gets mounted - and via that connection videos play.

So what is the file manager doing different to mount the drive?

To be clear - the box serving the disk is Ubuntu 22.04, the one attempting to mount the disk is Ubuntu 22.10

Edit: I'm trying to play the video by double clicking on the file name in file manager.  SMPlayer's log says that it can't open the file, no such name (the name it shows seems correct).  Note the problem is only with video files.  Everyother type I've tried, mp3, txt, etc, all seem file

Comment: The file manager uses gvfs, not cifs.

Comment: Depending on how your Samba server is configured, you may need to add `nounix` to your fstab options. This is something that I've seen interfere with streaming data connections over the years.

Comment: @matigo - I mount the drive manually using the shown command line.  I tried adding the "nounix" to the end of the -o options, didn't help.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: @OrganicMarble what would the command line look like to mount it the way file manager does?  I tried ```mount -t gvfs ...``` and its an unknown filesystem type

Comment: At least when I do it (Ubuntu MATE using caja file manager) The share gets mounted under `/run/user/1000/gvfs/` plus a long string starting with `smb-share...` I suspect your actual problem is in your cifs mount options. Why do you give `vers=1.0`? What error do you get when the "files won't play"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble I can't disagree that its *something* with the cifs options, but like I said, I've tried dozens.  The vers=1.0 is what worked before the box got upgraded from 22.04 to 22.10.  I've tried vers=2.0 and 3.0, and no vers... all nothing.  SMPlayer reports "MPlayer/mpv has finished unexpectedly.  Exit code: 2"

Comment: @OrganicMarble the drive is mounted by file manager in the same place, with a dir name "smb-share:server=fs1.local,share=misc"

Comment: In the cifs mounted share, can you access the movie file at all (for example, copy it to your local device)?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yes, copied to a local drive and it plays fine.  I added some more info in the original post if that gives any clues

Comment: Weird. It actually sounds like a problem with the player. If you try other players like vlc does it work?

Comment: @OrganicMarble Yup, tried two other players.  This has to be something that changed going from 22.04 to 22.10 - it all worked fine then.

Comment: @OrganicMarble well this is interesting...  From SMPlayer, I did "Open" then clicked on "/" it only shows bin, etc, home, lib, lib32, meta, snap, usr, and var.  Among the missing is "smb" where I have all the drives mounted.  ???  That would account for the name not being found, but why not?

Comment: Edit: Seems I was mistaken - I tried the built-in Video player when the problem first occured, not after all the gyrations... and indeed it does play the video.  So its something in SMPlayer that doesn't like a Samba drive in 22.10

Comment: Ah. Well, that does seem to make sense given all the other info. So your cifs mount is fine.

Comment: @OrganicMarble its still odd to me that it worked before the update, and works when the file manager mounts the disk.  There's gotta be some subtle thing that changed somewhere